# How to configure QoS on router?

Tags: router, qos

I want to prioritize applications which use the internet but in the QoS I find the applications are IGMP SIP H.323 MGCP SNMP DNS DHCP RIP RSTP RTCP RTP, I don't understand which of them is responsible for videos? or which is for firefox?

I can't understand what is Destination MAC? IP? Mask? Port Range? .. please give me a tutorial how to configure those things.

Comment: QOS is a huge subject. This question can't be answered here as the answer would be far too large.

Comment: I want a tutorial no need for explanations @RonMaupin

Comment: Recommendations are specifically off-topic for this forum. Please see the Help Center for which types of questions are allowed and which are not.